# kubectl get nodes from pod (NetworkPolicy)

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-networkpolicy

I try to run using Python `kubectl to get nodes` inside the POD.
How I should set up a Network Policy for this pod?

I tried to connect my namespace to the kube-system namespace, but it was not working.

Thanks.

Comment: think this does not has something to do with networkpolicy or maybe i get your question wrong. Actually you can use a serviceaccount with given roles to get this information. Isn't it?

Comment: Agree with Manuel, it probably has nothing to do with network policy. Do you get any error message when you're trying to list your nodes ? And how exacly you're doing it ? Do you use [Kubernetes Python Client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python) or just executing `kubectl` command from your python code ?

Answer (score 0):

As per [Accessing the API from a Pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/access-cluster/#accessing-the-api-from-a-pod):

> The recommended way to locate the apiserver within the pod is with the
> `kubernetes.default.svc` DNS name, which resolves to a Service IP which
> in turn will be routed to an apiserver.
>
> The recommended way to authenticate to the apiserver is with a service
> [account credential](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/). By kube-system, a pod is associated with a service account, and a credential (token) for that service account is placed into the filesystem tree of each container in that pod, at `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token`.

All you need is a service account with enough privileges, and use the API server DNS name as stated above. Example:

```
# Export the token value
export TOKEN=$(cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token)

# Use kubectl to talk internally with the API server
kubectl --insecure-skip-tls-verify=true  \
--server="https://kubernetes.default.svc:443" \
--token="${TOKEN}"                \
get nodes
```

*The Network Policy may be restrictive and prevent this type of call, however, by default, the above should work.*